# How to upsize Access 2013 to Sharepoint on Office365, but still keep synced "offline tables"

Tags: sharepoint, office365, ms-access-2013, upsizing

In a previous question ([Options for cloud based MS Access backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962689/options-for-cloud-based-ms-access-backend)) one poster, Albert D. Kallal, stated:

"...you could certainly consider to up-size your Access back end tables up to office 365 and continue to use your Access front end. And more amazing is with Access 2010 this means you get a "off line" and disconnected mode. This means that your application will continue to run EVEN WITH NO internet connection. The instant you find a wifi then the data sync process starts again. And this sync is not file based, but record based and is really replication built into the product and this setup requires ZERO extra code on your part."

I am looking for any pointers as to how I may do this. I have found how to export tables into Sharepoint (but from what I can see, there is then no local copy of the tables) and have also found how to convert to a web app - but but I can't seem to find anything about how to keep my current FE, have tables in Office365, and still get the "offline" mode whereby I can still access local copies of the BE tables when I have no internet access, as posted by Albert.

Any help, or links to appropriate content, would be appreciated

Please note I am relatively advanced when it comes to Access, but am totally new to Sharepoint/Office365.